# How do I change the JDK version in JDeveloper?

Tags: java, jdeveloper

I've been trying for a while now to get JDeveloper to use the latest JDK (17.0.1). I've searched around and the answers I've found have all said to change "SetJavaHome" in either jdev.conf or product.conf. I've tried both and both times when I tried to run JDeveloper it gave me a popup saying:

"You are attempting to run with Java 17.0.1

Running this product is supported with a minimum Java version of 1.8 and a maximum version less than 1.9.

Update SetJavaHome in
C:\Users\sudoc\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\12.2.1.4.0\product.conf to point to another Java.

This product will not be supported, and may not run correctly if you proceed.
Continue anyway?"

Since 1.8 is so far below 17, I feel like I might be trying to change the wrong thing. Any ideas? I'm running windows 11 and I just installed JDeveloper yesterday, so it should be the latest version.

Comment: Minimum Java version 1.8 maximum version lower than 1.9 => Only supported Java version is 1.8 / Java 8. Java 8 is an LTS release like 11 and 17 and is still supported.

Comment: @Robert I'm new to Java, so forgive me if this is a stupid question. Are you saying that an IDE released less than three years ago can only use a version of Java that's almost eight years old?

Comment: I was just interpreting the error message you posted. Keep in mind that your (latest) release of JDeveloper was released in September 2019, at that time Java 11 was just one year old and many Java programs were not ported to Java 11 (all the other versions are non-LTS which makes them in my opinion something right above "beta"). So Java 8 was a reasonable choice.

Answer (score -2):

JDK 1.8 has passed a test of time and its very common to use that but jdk 17 is latest version and this version has not passed test of time so its better to use 1.8 or maybe jdk 11 is good too.